# What is the correct way to pass an intent back to the original class after using the intent from the original class in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

If I am using an intent to pass string extras from class one to class two and then pass them again to class three, how do I pass the same intent back to class two?

I have a **Main Activity**, **Detail Activity**, and **Comments Activity**.

In the **Detail Activity** it is getting the string extras passed from the **Main Activity** and then passing the same data to the **Comments Activity** yet if I go to the **Comments Activity** and touch the back arrow in the toolbar to go back to the **Detail Activity** the app crashes because it is expecting the intent data again. So how would I ensure that the intent data gets passed back to the **Detail Activity**?

**Logcat**

> 04-03 02:29:21.902 23236-23236/com.curtrostudios.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.curtrostudios.testapp, PID: 23236
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.curtrostudios.testapp/com.curtrostudios.testapp.ProductDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.curtrostudios.testapp.ProductDetail.onCreate(ProductDetail.java:60)
>       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5334)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199) 
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5072) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 
>       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Line 60 in ProductDetail.java is `final String desc = intnt.getStringExtra("desc").toString();`

Comment: crash report please ?

Comment: @Kathi please see edit

Comment: check if `getIntent().getExtras() != null`, before doing that. If `null` then you are coming back from **comments activity** if not then you are here from **MainActivity**.

Comment: First of all: The "back arrow in the toolbar" is called *up* or *home*. Does it work if you press back (the real one, on the bottom)? This is probably easily fixed if you change your launchmode to singletop

Comment: @DavidMedenjak pressing the hardware back button works fine. The previous class displays the data as it should. It's only when using the "up" or "home" icon in the toolbar does it crash.

Comment: add launchMode="singleTop" to your detail/comment activities in the manifest and it should work properly

Comment: @DavidMedenjak That worked perfectly! Thank you very much!! Could you somehow post that as an answer so I can accept it and so it may help others that might run into the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about *launch modes*. With `standard`, the default, there will be just added a new activity to the stack.

Using *Up* or *Home* with a parent activity set, will launch the parent activity. This will create a new instance when the launchMode is set to `standard`, without the intent, leading to this NPE. The *Back Button* will just pop the stack, which is why it works when pressing back.

Use

```
launchMode="singleTop"
```

on your parent acitivities in the manifest.
By setting `launchMode=singleTop` in your Manifest, there will only be one instance of this activity on the stack—thus bringing your activity to the front, resuming where you left off.